# How to view SonarQube report in Azure devops dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

I want to view the report generated through SonarQube in Azure devops dashboard or in the build summary,i tried to follow this link: [How to view the SonarQube full analysis report in the build summary in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554274/how-to-view-the-sonarqube-full-analysis-report-in-the-build-summary-in-azure-dev)    but it didn't worked.

if anyone has solution for this please post it here,Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 1):

We can see the report in the build page.

Steps:

1. Install the extension [SonarQube](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) and Add SonarQube service connection.
2. Add the task Prepare Analysis Configuration to prepare analysis on SonarQube and publish Quality Gate results.
3. Publish Quality Gate Result task is to display the Quality Gate status in the build summary.
4. Then we can see the SonarQube report in the Extension tab.

Please refer to this [doc](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/) for more details.